# IE7 CSS headache

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am building a site at the moment and the contact page is ruined in IE7.  I have tried everything to fix it, but nothing is working.

The link is,

http://www-magnificent-7-co-uk.consultcreatecommunicate.com

Any ideas any one, basically the right hand side of the form should be in 2 columns....the layout of each column should label input label input.

Comment: Could you please rephrase this sentence "Any ideas any one, basically right hand side of the for should 2 labels then text inputs below them, then 2 more labels and two more text inputs."

Comment: Post an example illustrating the issue on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: How is a fiddle different to a direct link to the problem?

Comment: @sico87 a fiddle will separate the problem into a smaller chunk. No one likes to go through an entire page of code trying to find what's wrong. I think it is also in the guidelines

Comment: I'll try and sort it out then, but I'm in an iPhone at the moment